# Power shell command in python output gives integer. Why?

Tags: python, powershell, integer

```
import os
policyINAppconfigFile = os.system('%SYSTEMROOT%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -Command  "findstr "maxAllowedContentLength" C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\inetsrv\\config\\applicationHost.config "')
numbers = []
for word in policyINAppconfigFile.split():
    if word.isdigit():
        numbers.append(int(word))
print(numbers)
```

The code above gives the error output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Administrator/Documents/IIS code/testing123.py", line 119, in 
    for word in policyINAppconfigFile.split():
builtins.AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: policyINAppconfigFile is integer number. You can't split it. Maybe you want to split it as string value?

Comment: when i try to split like this:                                                                policyINAppconfigFile = str(policyINAppconfigFile)
policyINAppconfigFile = policyINAppconfigFile.split()
print(policyINAppconfigFile)                                                                                                    It returns ['0'] which i have no idea why. @Yoskutik

Comment: What is policyINAppconfigFile supposed to be? What is the aim of your code?

Comment: I am doing Window IIS policy based on CIS benchmark and i am trying to use powershell command to extract the maxAllowedContentLength policy from the applicationHost.config file which gives the output <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="40000000" /> in powershell. Afterwards i am trying to use the powershell command output to extract the value 40000000 to check against auditor input. @Yoskutik

Comment: 40000000 is a number. Do you need to split in into ['4', '0', ..., '0']?

Comment: Nope. I just want to extract the value 40000000 from the powershell command output <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="40000000" /> but when i try to split it, it says int object has no attribute split and also when i try to add the output to a List, it doesn't add the powershell command output to the List, it adds a integer value 0 to list instead. @Yoskutik

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command via `os.system` you get the exit code back; not the return value. The subprocess module is great for grabbing the output of a command:

```py
import subprocess
import os

power_shell = os.path.join(
    os.environ["SYSTEMROOT"], "System32",
    "WindowsPowerShell", "v1.0", "powershell.exe"
)

policyINAppconfigFile = subprocess.check_output(
    [power_shell, "-Command",  "findstr maxAllowedContentLength",
    "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\inetsrv\\config\\applicationHost.config"]
)
```

Comment: Ohh this helps! I will just try to trial and error with my code now with what with you have given. Thank you!

Comment: @Javier if above is the answer please mark it as such!